# Should I mention my reference's university role (administrative) when listing?

Tags: university, citations

I have a list of references in my CV. One of them happens to be the Dean of the graduate school and the other a Vice Chancellor. Both of these roles are administrative and their primary position is that of a Professor. Would listing these referees as

```
John H. Doeberg
Professor and Dean of the Graduate School
University of Foo

Jane Q. Publicowski
Professor and Vice Chancellor of Academic Affairs
University of Bar
```

be better (give more credence/weight) than simply listing them as a Professor. I know that ultimately what they write in those letters is what matters, but for the purposes of this question, it can be safely assumed that both letters are going to be stellar recommendations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to remember here is that your reference letter writers will be providing official letters, and therefore will be including their full titles (presumably the letterhead will list this). In such a case, it doesn't really seem to make much sense to "hide" the status of the person writing the letter. Moreover, if the position is one which will include some administrative duties, a letter of reference from someone doing university administration might even be a plus.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what the letters are for. If it's for a position based on academic credentials (whether in academia or industry), I doubt it makes much of a difference. If the position involves administrative responsibilities, then mentioning this would help, so the people requesting the letter would make sure to ask them.

Comment: They are for an academic/research position with possibly minor administrative responsibilities...